# Different instances of java classes in a SOAP connection

Tags: java, web-services, soap

I am making a hangman game as a school project. It's a part of a distributed system, where I want to be able to run several clients on the gameserver. The clients communicate with the server via SOAP. But my problem is they all guess the same word at the same time. I want it to create a different instance for each connected client, but I'm a bit lost in this one.

My server code is in the box below:

```
public class Galgeserver {
    public static void main(String[] arg) throws Exception {
        GalgeI g = new Galgelogik();
        Endpoint.publish("http://[::]:9924/galgeleg", g);
    }
}
```

Galgelogik is the games logic, and GalgeI is the webservice class.

I'm using Netbeans EE 8.2

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit confused about why you're confused :(

1) Every "server" has a "listener"

2) The listener "accepts" new incoming connections from clients.

3) If you spawn a new thread for each new connection, then multiple connections may be serviced in parallel.  Otherwise, you'll have to wait for one connection to finish before you can start the next.

4) Either way, each client/server connection is INDEPENDENT of another.

In other words: yes, each time you "accept" a new connection ... you get a new socket ... and you can (and, in general, should) create a new class instance to handle that client.

Here is a good tutorial (one of many):

http://www.baeldung.com/a-guide-to-java-sockets

PS:

I'm not sure how you're planning on implementing your SOAP web service, or what IDE and compiler you're using.

If you don't have any definite preferences already, please read this tutorial:

[Java web development with Eclipse WTP](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseWTP/article.html)